# How to run logistic regression using simulated data {data has 50 observations and 100 simulations, in 1 CSV file}

Tags: r

I have tried to run the code I wrote but it is not giving me results.

```
fitlist <- list()
for(i in unique(mydata1$Sim)){
  dat <- mydata1[mydata1$Sim==i,]
  tmp <- try(append(fitlist, model1 <- glm(y ~ x1+x2, family = binomial(link = logit),
                                           data = dat)))
  if (class(tmp) != "try-error") fitlist <- append(fitlist, tmp)

}
```

I want the results to be like a table so that I can write to them as a CSV file. I am interested in the coefficients beta0, beta1 and beta2 then the standard errors and confidence interval.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dat)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dat, 20))`.

Comment: https://github.com/Seanlove89/logitdata                        I have attached the sample data. Thanks for the code still running it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what the question asks for in a simple way.
Untested, since there is no data.

```
sp <- split(mydata1, mydata1$Sim)
model_list <- lapply(sp, function(dat){
  tryCatch(glm(y ~ x1+x2, family = binomial(link = logit), data = dat),
           error = function(e) e)
})

ok <- !sapply(model_list, inherits, 'error')
fitlist <- model_list[ok]
```

Comment: I am using the lbreg command to fit a log-binomial distribution. I am trying to change fitlist to a dataframe but I am getting this error. **Error in as.data.frame.default(value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"lbreg"’ to a data.frame**    The code i tried to use to change fitlist to dataframe was `library(tidyverse)
p <- fitlist %>% 
  map_df(as_tibble)`   @Rui Barradas

Comment: @Seanlove OK, but in the question you run `glm`, not `lbreg`.

Comment: Yes the code is working so my question is how can I change fitlist to a dataframe. The reason I change to lbreg from glm was convergence problems with log-binomial.

Comment: As for `glm` there is `fitlist %>% broom::tidy() %>% as.data.frame()`. As for `lbreg` you will have to decide what members of the return value you want to be in the dataframe, there is no off the shelf function for that.